# Flow: accept multiple types as function arguments

Tags: flowtype

I’m trying to get function c to accept two types. The types are the same except for the optional `id` property in Foo. Flow errors on this even if I check for the existence of `id` before using it. I tried searching here and in the docs but I couldn’t find anything.

```
type Foo = {
  bar: string,
  id?: string,
}

type Bar = {
  bar: string,
};

const a = (args: Bar) => {
  b(args);
}

const c = (args: Foo) => {
  b(args);
}

const b = ({ bar, id }: Bar | Foo) => {
  // As soon as you use id here Flow errors out, even though id is optional
  // and I check for it’s existence.
  if (id) {
    console.log(id);
  }
}
```

[View a working example on Try Flow](https://flow.org/try/#0C4TwDgpgBAYg9nKBeKBvAUFKAjAhgJwC4oBnYfASwDsBzAGkygoBMB+Ysy2hgX3XVCQoAIQLI0jPEVLlq9dDwDc-AMZwqZKLnEAKAjRLFR+AJTIAfBKzY9+AyeV90ajcCgrd+w7ARmkljGtbe0dVdU1sXVQcAjomZigeIzEAHx84PwDGCgAzKB0WMwwASBcSOAAbCAA6CrgaAuYHRj4eIA)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Flow currently (v0.69) has some weaknesses over object destructuring, you can achieve what you want without destructuring:

```
const b = (obj: Bar | Foo) => {
  if (obj.id) {
    console.log(obj.id)
  }
}
```

Comment: This works, thanks for helping out! Definitely hope this is something the Flow team tackles soon :)